# Integrate Zend Framework 1 and Doctrine 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I would like to use Doctrine (v2.4) in my ZendFramework (v1.11) application, which I am starting from scratch. There are some articles describing such integration, but they seem quite complicated and a little out of date. Is there any fairly simple way to connect ZF1 and Doctrine2?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this as an application resource (extending `\Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract`)

The code is quite long so below is a top level check list of the requirements.

- Create a doctrine entity manager configuration instance (`Doctrine\ORM\Configuration`).

  `$config  = new Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();`
- Populate the configuration with the required data (metadata driver, cache config etc). Doctrine's documentation is a good reference here to what would be required (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html)

Example here uses the Annotation driver:

```
$driver = new Driver\AnnotationDriver(
  new Annotations\CachedReader(new Annotations\AnnotationReader(), new  Cache\ArrayCache()), 
  $entityDirs
 );
 $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
```

- Lastly pass this new config instance to the static entity manager `EntityManager::create`

E.G. (`$options` here is the database connection info as exampled in the above link)

```
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($options['database'], $config);
```

Take a look at my full source, at the very least it will give you a head start:

https://github.com/alex-patterson-webdev/Multiverse/blob/master/lib/Multiverse/Application/Resource/Entitymanager.php